# In Python, check if executed as root

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, permissions, root

How can I check if my program is running with root permission. Does Pathlib offer the possibility to query the USER-ID under Linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can access username with standard library package `getpass`

```
import getpass
print(getpass.getuser())
```

when code is executed with sudo or as root, user is root